# Bind data to a db container

Tags: docker

I have a test data which I build as a Docker image (docker build with copy to /db/data) and pushed to docker hub.

I want to run a db instance that will use that data.

I would expect to be able to:

1. run a "docker create" and create a container from image and map it to a volume (maybe named volume) which will practically will copy the data to that volume.
2. run a "docker run" with volumes-from and map that data from first container to the second.

When I tried it out I always see that in the second directory there is a folder mapping but I can't reach any pre-populated data from the data-container.

Answer (score 0):

`--volumes-from` will add "Volume" from a docker container to another.

In your case you created an **image** that contains your data, you didnt create a **volume** that contains your data.

Docker is currently supporting the following:

- a host bind mount that is listed as a bind mount in both services
- a named volume that is used by both services
- volumes_from another service

for example if you have your data in /my/data on docker host you can use the following:

```
sudo docker run -d --name firstcontainer -v /my/data:/db/data <image name>
sudo docker run -d --name secondcontainer -v /my/data:/db/data <image name>
```

If you want to use named volumes follow these steps:

1. create the named volume

   ```
   sudo docker volume create <volumename>
   ```
2. Mount it to a transitional container and copy your data in it with `docker cp`

   ```
   sudo docker cp /path/to/your/file <containername>:/destination/path
   ```
3. Mount your named volume on multiple containers.

   ```
   sudo docker run -d --name firstcontainer -v <volumename>:/db/data <image name>
   sudo docker run -d --name secondcontainer -v <volumename>:/db/data <image name>
   ```

Comment: My issue is with "Mount it to a transitional container and copy your data in it with docker copy". 

Let's say I have a Dockerfile with two lines:
``FROM scratch
COPY a.txt /data``

and you build it as foo/goo image in Docker-Hub.

And let's assume I have a created a named volume 'my-volume'.
How do I insert the a.txt inside the volume so another (let's say a simple ubuntu container) can use it (cat a.txt for example)?

Comment: From your answer I see I may not explained myself properly.  In step 2 show how you pull data from DockerHub and populate <volume> with it.

Comment: You should decouple your application data from the container, so you shouldnt use dockerhub for this.